# Empty data response from Facebook API, using app access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Code that I had written to fetch a Facebook page's posts using an app access token has suddenly stopped working. The JSON response's `data` object is an empty array. I'm not getting any error messages. When I try making the same request using an access token generated by the Graph API explorer, I get back a valid JSON response containing data. I've tried resetting my app's secret and generating a new access token, but I still get back an empty `data` object.

When I use the Facebook access token debugger, the only information returned is the App ID.

I generated my app access token by making a GET request to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<app_secret>&grant_type=client_credentials`

I don't have control over the page I'm trying to fetch data from, but I can contact the admin. Are there any permissions I should have them check?

Without any error messages or feedback, I'm at a loss on how to debug this. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Have you already try your query on graph explorer? Does it return the same result?  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Yes, I tried the same query on graph explorer using a token provided by FB and it returns a valid response containing data.

Comment: For me its the same approach and the same result.

Comment: It seems it has been fixed recently isnt it?

Comment: `/page_id/feed` works for me without any special permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/sonu/pen/wEciK/)

```
token = 'valid_access_token';
page = '20531316728';
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+page+'/feed?access_token="+token+"&fields=id,message&limit=10';
    comments = [];
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'url': url,
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
      $('.result').html(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    'error': function(data){
      $('.result').html(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```